# Prononciation de « fluctuat nec mergitur »

Tags: prononciation, latin

C'est la devise de la ville de Paris. Comment est-ce que les Français la prononcent - en particulier, est-ce que l'on prononce le « t » à la fin de *fluctuat* et le « c » à la fin de *nec* ?

Comment: Si mes vieux souvenirs de latin sont encore valables, je dirais «oui», on prononce toutes les lettres.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about latin, not french.

Comment: It's the motto of Paris, so my question is about how the French pronounce it in that context.

Comment: @lkl I agree with Édouard... the fact that it's Paris' motto doesn't change the fact that it's a Latin phrase. Everyone does their best Latin impression. It's kind of like asking how to say *crème brûlée* in English.

Comment: But if you ask about crème brûlée here on the French forum, you'll get a completely different answer than if you ask on an English forum. If you want the English pronunciation, you ask on the latter. I wanted (and got) the French pronunciation of this Latin phrase here. What if I wanted to know how to pronounce "a priori"? That's Latin, but it's used all the time in French.

Comment: Plus, there are almost as many pronunciations of Latin as there are languages. Frenchmen pronounce Latin a way, Englishmen another, Italians pronounce it almost as their own language. Still, @Ikl, to make things less debatable, maybe you could rewrite the question to include elements that would undeniably link it to the French language.

Comment: I don't get why there is that much eagerness to close this question as off topic. It was obvious from the beginning the question was about how Frenchmen, not the Englishmen or whoever, pronounce this expression which should be considered built from the French lexicon, just like "Nec plus ultra" officially is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il existe deux prononciations courantes.

Dans la première, le u est prononcé /y/. C'est celle de Georges Brassens dans « Les copains d'abord », peut-être pour la rime avec littérature.

Dans la deuxième, plus conforme à la prononciation traditionnelle du latin, le u est prononcé /u/ (ou).

Dans tous les cas, toutes les consonnes sont prononcées.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a de plus le problème du "gi" dans mergitur : les petits Français qui apprennent le latin aujourd'hui savent qu'il faut prononcer ce "gi" comme dans "guitare". Leurs parents et les personnes plus âgées ont appris à l'inverse à le prononcer comme dans "gitane". Ceci est dû au fait que l'enseignement du latin a contraint les enseignants à utiliser la prononciation reconstituée du latin, plus proche de la réalité.